# show/hide component on certain url in the nav bar react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, show-hide, react-component

I'm trying to hyde links in the navbar when user go on certain pages. For example when user goes on Landing page I'm trying to hide Orders and Basket and leave just Login Link. Not sure how to implement that. Will appreciate your help as I'm quite new to React Js.
Here is my code:

```
function Header() {
const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

const handleAuthentication = () => {
    if (user) {
        auth.signOut();
    }
}

    return (
        
        <nav className="header bg-dark">

           <Link to="/home">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faStoreAlt} className= "header__logo m-1"/>
            </Link>

            {/* Links */}
            <Link to="/landing">
         <div className="header__right ">Laanding</div>
            </Link>

            <div className="header__nav ">
                <Link to={!user && "/login"} className="header__link">
                <div onClick={handleAuthentication} className="header__option">
                    <span className="header__optionLineOne">Hello, {!user ? 'Guest' : user.email}</span>
                    <span className="header__optionLineTwo">{user ? 
                    'Sing Out' : 'Sing In'}</span>
                </div>
                </Link>

                <Link to="/orders" className="header__link">
                <div className="header__option">
                    <span className="header__optionLineOne">Returns</span>
                    <span className="header__optionLineTwo">Orders</span>
                </div>
                </Link>

                <Link to="/checkout">
                    <div className="header__optionBasket">
                        {/* Shopping basket icon */}
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShoppingBasket}/>
                        {/* Number of items in the basket */}
                        <span className="header__optionLineTwo 
                        header__basketCount">{basket?.length}</span>
                    </div>
                </Link>

            </div>        
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help:

```
if(Window.location == your_url) {
var navBar = document.queryselector('your_navbar');

navBar.parentNode.removeChild(navBar);
}
```